# Proving a determinant equal a 0

Tags: matrices, determinant

How can I prove that this type of determinant is equal to zero. I couldn't figure out how to start this test or any counter-test. If p is one, the determinant is null. How to begin?

$
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
(1 - p)a_1 & a_2 & \dots  & a_n \\
a_1 & (1 - p)a_2 & \dots & a_n  \\
\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots \\
a_1 & a_2 & \dots & (1 - p)a_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$

Comment: The case $n=1$ shows *precisely* that the determinant is not always zero, and that there are missing hypothesis.

Comment: The determinant is always $0$ with $p=0$, not with $p=1$, for $n \ge 2$. Look at the $n=2$ case

Comment: In the case $n=2$, the determinant is $a_1\cdot a_2\cdot p(p-2)$ which is only $0$ (even if $a_1$ and $a_2$ are not) , if $p=0$ or $p=2$.

Comment: You can also look at $A^T$. If any $a_i$ is zero, $A^T$ has a zero row and hence determinant zero. If no $a_i$ is zero, you can use elementary row operations to remove all the $a_i$. This gives a much easier matrix to analyse further. I think you'll find that it only has zero determinant when $p=0$ or $p=n$.

Comment: And for $p=2$ , the case $n=3$ gives determinant $4\cdot a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3$ , hence here the only possibility for $D=0$ is that one of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ is $0$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Good comment, however we need not the transpose, since a $0$-column also gives immediateldy $D=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is $(-1)^n a_1 \cdots a_n p^{n-1}(p-n)$ and so is zero iff $a_k=0$ for some $k$ or $p=0$ or $p=n$.

This follows from the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), since $A=D+B$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $B$ has rank $1$.